# Resilience4j circuit breaker configuration in yml

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml, resilience4j

I have multiple circuit breakers for different API call and all have the same configuration as below.

CB1:

registerHealthIndicator: true
slidingWindowSize: 10
permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED
minimumNumberOfCalls: 20
waitDurationInOpenState: 50s
failureRateThreshold: 50
eventConsumerBufferSize: 10

CB2:
registerHealthIndicator: true
slidingWindowSize: 10
permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED
minimumNumberOfCalls: 20
waitDurationInOpenState: 50s
failureRateThreshold: 50
eventConsumerBufferSize: 10

CB3:
registerHealthIndicator: true
slidingWindowSize: 10
permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED
minimumNumberOfCalls: 20
waitDurationInOpenState: 50s
failureRateThreshold: 50
eventConsumerBufferSize: 10

Instead of giving the same configuration multiple times, I want to give this configuration in one place and use it for all services in the same yml file. Kind of function call in yml which give me the required config like below.

In yaml:
CB1:
getconfig()
CB:2
getconfig()

And getconfig will return the below configuration.
registerHealthIndicator: true
slidingWindowSize: 10
permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED
minimumNumberOfCalls: 20
waitDurationInOpenState: 50s
failureRateThreshold: 50
eventConsumerBufferSize: 10

Thanks in advance.

CB1:
CB2:
registerHealthIndicator: true
slidingWindowSize: 10
permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED
minimumNumberOfCalls: 20
waitDurationInOpenState: 50s
failureRateThreshold: 50
eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
But this is giving an error.

Comment: check this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-resilience4j